# How to factory reset Force10 Release 8.3.7.1

Tags: force10

Force10 Release 8.3.7.1 
 NetBSD 1.6.1 (S4810) #0: Thu Apr  7 09:04:27 PDT 2011

I've tried to interrupt the normal boot with a serial connector and I can stop  the boot but in this version I can't reset the configuration I can only change the boot image.

It doesn't have:
 an options menu
 the reset command has not been implemented

It seems I'd need to boot from a tftp sever but I don't have the image to write to the tftp server.